# Paypal express show tax amount but not add in to total

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal express checkout method in mysite built in php CodeIgniter.

I want that the tax amount that is showing while paying on paypal site should still show but should not add into total amount, as I already have prices of items including taxes.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, have a look at the docs to see if you can pass a custom label with the tax value https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible yet but there are 2-3 tricks which you can apply to achieve this.
1. dont add tax for paypal checkout.

OR

2. add tax as 0.00 and a label with saying total amount including tax etc.

OR

3. at the time of sending item amount to paypal deduct tax amount from each item of cart. and then paypal will add them .